# File data do not fall into controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

Image file data do not fall into my controller. I send files with type `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` files.

This is my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( new { @action = "/Upload",  @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @method = "POST" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Label("Pictures:", new { @class = "control-label  col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, new { @type = "file", @name = "files", @id = "files", @style = "width: 100%;", @multiple = "multiple" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divfiles"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
      var files = evt.target.files;
      var divfiles = document.getElementById('divfiles');
      while (divfiles.hasChildNodes()) {
          divfiles.removeChild(divfiles.lastChild);
      }
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            var imgLoad = document.createElement('img');
            imgLoad.setAttribute("id", "imgLoad");
            imgLoad.setAttribute("style", "width:10%;");
            imgLoad.setAttribute("src", e.target.result);
            imgLoad.setAttribute("title", escape(theFile.name));
            span.appendChild(imgLoad);
            divfiles.insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
}
```

This is my controller

Here my images aren`t come

```
// GET:
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var rooms = db.Rooms.Include(r => r.Hotel).Include(r => r.RoomType);
    return View(rooms.ToList());
}

// GET: Rooms/Details/
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Room room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
    if (room == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(room);
}

// GET: Rooms/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    RoomViewModel model = new RoomViewModel();
    model.HotelIDs = from c in db.Hotels
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = c.Name,
                        Value = c.Id.ToString()
                    };

    model.RoomTypeIDs = from t in db.RoomTypes
                   select new SelectListItem
                   {
                       Text = t.Name,
                       Value = t.Id.ToString()
                   };
    model.EquipmentIDs = from k in db.Equipments
                      select new SelectListItem
                      {
                          Text = k.Name,
                          Value = k.Id.ToString()
                      };

    //ViewBag.HotelId = new SelectList(db.Hotels, "Id", "Name");
    //ViewBag.RoomTypeId = new SelectList(db.RoomTypes, "Id", "Name");
    //ViewBag.EquipmentsIds = new MultiSelectList(db.Equipments, "Id", "Name");
    return View(model);
}
// POST: Rooms/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, RoomViewModel roomViewModel, int[]EquipmentIDs )
{

Room room = new Room();
    room.HotelId = roomViewModel.HotelId;
    room.RoomTypeId = roomViewModel.RoomTypeId;
    room.MaxPeople = roomViewModel.MaxPeople;
    room.WindowView = roomViewModel.WindowView;
    room.Price = roomViewModel.Price;
    room.IsDeleted = roomViewModel.IsDeleted;
    if (EquipmentIDs == null)
    {
        foreach (int EquipmentID in EquipmentIDs)
        {
            var eqp = db.Equipments.Where(t => t.Id == EquipmentID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (eqp != null)
            {
                if (room.Equipments == null)
                {
                    room.Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
                }
                room.Equipments.Add(eqp);
            }
        }
    }

    //room.RoomsPhotos = roomViewModel.files;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Rooms.Add(room);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{

    return View("Index", "Hotels");

}
```

In method Upload files (IEnumerable files) doesn't come.

Comment: can you provide network debug from chrome developer tools just to see what is inside the http session. i guess is something with the binding and the name of the field

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not producing the correct `form` tag. For file upload to work, you form should have the `enctype` attribute value set to `"multipart/form-data"`

Your current view code is rendering a form tag like this (*Check the view source of the page*)

```
<form action="/Upload?enctype=multipart%2Fform-data&amp;method=POST" method="post"> 

</form>
```

But for the upload to work, ideally it should be like

```
<form action="/Upload"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 

</form>
```

If you use the `Html.BeginForm` helper method properly, It will generate the correct form tag markup as above.

This should work

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
                                              new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```

Assuming your `Upload` action method is in the `HomeController`. If it is a different controller, update the second parameter of the `Html.BeginForm method` call.

Answer (score 0):

If `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` not working, try this one:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload()
{
  var file = request.files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reviewed your code.
I believe the problem is your form tag.

Instead of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm( new { @action = "/Upload",  @enctype = "multipart/form-data", @method = "POST" }))
```

Please try this

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("yourActionMethod", "yourController")" method="post">
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Label("Pictures:", new { @class = "control-label  col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, new { @type = "file", @name = "files", @id = "files", @style = "width: 100%;", @multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divfiles"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 
</form>
```

You could also change your script, one of the best ways to send or recieve data from a .Net Core controller, is with AJAX.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
Here's the link. It will make writing such code ten times easier. :))